# Android Phonegap 3.3.0 and Email Composer plugin Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-3

I installed phonegap 3.3.0 via the command line, created app, added android platform OK. I can use the latest Android ADT to import phonegap app and test it on my Android device. Everything worked perfect.

I installed the Email Composer plugin https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer via the command line

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer.git
```

The plugin seems install ok, however when I tried to run the javascript code

```
window.plugin.email.open();
```

I got error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'open' of undefined:43
```

I put the email_composer.js inside js folder and in my index.html I add  reference to it. Not sure why I get this error.

I already asked the author here https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer/issues/9 and he answered:

```
You lead the plugin in the wrong way. Do not lead the plugins directly. 
If you install a plugin through the command line interface, 
they will be listed in the cordova_plugins.js file which is loaded 
by cordova.js.
```

I looked up the file cordova_plugins.js I only saw these code:

```
cordova.define('cordova/plugin_list', function(require, exports, module) {
module.exports = [];
module.exports.metadata = 
// TOP OF METADATA
{}
// BOTTOM OF METADATA
});
```

I should see something about email_composer.js in this file, right? If so, then what I should write in here.

This is my first time using phonegap plugin, not sure what to do. Hope someone can help

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Always remember to 'prepare' your app after installing any new plugin. From the app's root:
    `cordova prepare android` 
This should update your cordova_plugins.js file

Answer (score 0):

I found the bug. I got error if I call the javascript like this

```
window.plugin.email.open();
```

To make it works, call like this:

```
window.plugin.open();
```

(remove "email")

Hope this help someone